# Term to indicate how much force one needs to exert to steer the wheels of a car

Tags: steering, terminology

What is the proper term to indicate how much force the driver needs to exert to steer the wheels of a car?

Comment: Uhh, "steering wheel turning force" maybe? You sure there is a unique dedicated term?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I have no idea :)

Answer (score 6):

The force required for the driver to turn the steering wheel would be a torque measured in foot-pounds (or Newton-meters).

Extra Credit: 
The actual force required for the rack in a rack and pinion style steering system to push/pull the tie-rods to turn the wheels would be a simple load measured in pounds or kilograms. The actual load the tires experience when trying to turn would again be a torque.

Comment: Well, those are the units of measurement, not the actual term. Unless that's what the OP was asking.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Torque is the "term to indicate how much force" as OP requested, ft-lb is the unit of measurement.

Comment: Sorry, my question was indeed unclear, I was looking for the actual term and not the unit. However, it's nice to know the unit as well  :) Also, thanks for the extra credit!

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the term "steering effort" used, seems appropriate. It's not quantifiable, but it gets the idea across.